# How to replace text using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble replacing the text "I wish to give an additional contribution of:"

Here is the HTML:

```
<tr id="PC1930_Wizard1_trAdditionalDonation">
<td style="text-align:left;" colspan="2" class="BBFieldCaption">
I wish to give an additional contribution of:&nbsp;
<span id="PC1930_Wizard1_lblCurrency">$</span>
<input type="text" style="width:75px;" class="BBFormTextbox"       id="PC1930_Wizard1_txtAdditionalDonation" name="PC1930$Wizard1$txtAdditionalDonation">
</td>
</tr>
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
$('.BBFieldCaption:contains("I wish")').text('new text');
```

Here is the link to JSFiddle with the complete HTML:

http://jsfiddle.net/jelane20/LnrJU/

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery in your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LnrJU/1/. When you do, it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the jquery library and Wrap the code in `Document ready()`.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LnrJU/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jQuery on your page. Your JSFiddle demo didn't have jQuery included: 
[**working JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/LnrJU/4/).

You may also want to consider wrapping your jQuery code within a document `ready()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.BBFieldCaption:contains("I wish")').text('new text');
});
```

However as there is only one element with a class of "BBFieldCaption", you could just use:

```
$('.BBFieldCaption').text('new text');
```

Comment: The same class is used on other sections in the page, I have to specify that only that specific string changes

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include jQuery to make it works.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LnrJU/5/)**

But actually, your code will remove the `span` and `input` element as well.

Other better solution is to use [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) and [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) only the text that you want to change:

```
$(".BBFieldCaption").contents().filter(function(){ 
    return this.nodeType == 3; 
}).first().replaceWith("new text");
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LnrJU/6/)**